# Cannot emulate JetPack Compose TextField colors programatically using themes

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I have a compose element in my app that contains two ExposedDropddownMenu and one Column that itself contains Checkbox elements, as seen in the following image.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VN2uG.png)

The TextField element inside ExposedDropodownMenu is using the application theme based on Material3 Compose themes, so all colors are the defaults.

The third element on the right is a column which I want to look similar to TextField elements.

**Problem**

I already set the column background color, its height, and the rounded corners to look like TextField, and I drew a line in the bottom, but I cannot make the line color the same as Indicator line in the TextField.

I already checked the M3 documentation and it says that *onSurfaceVariant* is the corresponding color but it does not look the same.

I even tried to use explicit Black color, but it didn't work.

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahHqZ.png)

This is my code on the Column element.

```
val borderColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant

...

Column(
   modifier = modifier
      .background(
         color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant,
         shape = ShapeDefaults.ExtraSmall
      )
   .heightIn(min = 56.dp)
   .drawBehind {
      val strokeWidth = 1.dp.value * density * 0.5f
      val y = size.height - strokeWidth * 2f
      drawLine(
         color = borderColor,
         Offset(0f, y),
         Offset(size.width, y),
         strokeWidth
      )
   }
   .padding(top = 8.dp, start = 16.dp, bottom = 8.dp, end = 16.dp)
)
```